# How to read a value from a website from WP7 App

Tags: web-services, windows-phone-7, rss

I'm developing a currency converter Application for Windows phone 7. And i set the value manually, I want to know how to read the Currency values from specific web service.... let's say from this web site... http://www.cbsl.gov.lk/htm/english/_cei/er/e_1.asp
How to do it.... thanks in advance...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If i understand your suggestion above, i advise you not to slice/hack HTML webpages in order to extract data such as conversion rates. The reason is that the day the webpage structure changes it would break your application. Best is to find an API that you can contact and request the data you need. You can check on a search engine for APIs for currency rates. For example, i found this one. http://openexchangerates.org/latest.json

So, once you have selected an API, you can use WebClient to call it and then handle the responses.

Answer (score 0):

You have to get the page HTML and then parse the resulting text to find the data you require.

There is an open-source [Currency Converter](http://currency.codeplex.com) application available in Codeplex you can check in order to see how to achieve the expected result.